# How can i insert data in table with a join sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

i have 2 tables on db.
First table:

users

id|name|mail|password|group

second table

scores

id|name|score

The idea is get the name from users using the id (this id already know because i get that by php), then insert a score in table scores using the name obtained by a id.

I suppose that can i do with a inner join between users and scores.

How can i do that?

Comment: Once you get the user's name with a SELECT, you can simply add the record in the classic way that you know.

Comment: You don't need to join.. you can directly add to score table since you already get the username.

Answer (score 3):

```
Insert into scores(id, name, score)
    select ID, name, score(that you can pass)
    from users
    where id = (parameter pass by PHP)
```

Comment: This is the better solution because all the columns are listed in the `insert`.

Answer (score 2):

Agree. You can simply use this:

```
INSERT INTO scores values (null, (select name from users where users.id= 1),100);
```

Replace the score and id with the values you get. 
Assume you have the auto increment for your ids.

Comment: Thanks!, and if i want to update the value after? i need to use a update sentence?, how i do that?

Comment: @user3565613 In the PHP code, you can just update the sql statement with parameters like `"insert into scores values (null, (select name from users where users.id=". $userIid ."), ". $score .")"`